# How do I perform a coder review of all Drupal modules using coder?

Tags: php, bash, drupal, drupal-modules

I am using a bash script and am trying to cycle through the modules however it is not working. That is the logs created are empty.

```
for MOD in {space separated list of modules to run coder against};
 do drush coder checkstyle ${MOD} > logs/coder- ${MOD}.xml 2>/dev/null
 done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can go to the drupal modules page here there is the link of the code review with the description or you can read the whole documentation here http://drupal.org/node/144172